# problems when trying to pass data into the keras.utlis.normalize function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a small data analysis project (for myself) and I have ran into a problem :o

here's my code :)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

data = pd.read_csv("game_Statistics.csv")

#prepare data

#drop useless columns
data.drop(columns=['Date', 'Mental State', 'Assists', 'Revives', 'Hits','Head Shots'], inplace=True)

#format time of day to an easyily processable integer
for i in range(len(data['Time of Day'])):
    data['Time of Day'][i] = data['Time of Day'][i].replace(" AM", "")
    data['Time of Day'][i] = data['Time of Day'][i].replace(" PM", "")
    data['Time of Day'][i] = data['Time of Day'][i].replace(":00:00", "")

for i in range(len(data['Accuracy'])):
    data['Accuracy'][i] = int(data['Accuracy'][i].replace("%", ""))

y = data['Placed'].values
x = data.drop(columns=['Placed'])
x = x[:].values

x = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x, axis=1)
```

[image: the x variable]

I believe the problem is in the x data set (which I need to be an array) when it's passing into the normalize function

error

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable conjugate method
```

(traced to the normalize function)

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Check the result of `type(x[:].values)` and `print(x[:].values)`, as that's what you pass to the `tf.keras.utils.normalize()` function. Your error says that there are strings where as the method needs a `numpy.array` or some other object that has a `.conjugate()` method.

Comment: @Jason i added an image of what it said in variable explorer

Comment: As you assign to the variable name `x` 3 times there's no way for me to know which `x` is in your image, if you use the approach suggested in my first comment you'll be able to see the type and and contents of `x` immediately before you pass it to `tf.keras.utils.normalize()`

Comment: @Jason I understand now, I fixed the string problem but now. the x values are looking like  `[12 3 29 570.68 78 50 343 509 1777]`, so the list is not delimited by commas, is there a different way to call the `x[:].values ` code block so that it is delimited correctly?

Comment: Can you tell me the results of `type(x[:].values)`? You'll need to check that particular line in your code to make sure that all the values are numerical types e.g `int`/`float` etc. How to go about converting/fixing the issue depend on the type of object that you're dealing with.

Comment: @Jason `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: i figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

figured out the problem :)

> the normalize function does not take floats, so you need to make sure that the data type is integer :o

solution:

```
x = data.drop(columns=['Placed']).to_numpy(dtype="int64')
```

this will create a NumPy array that will be in int64 and processable by the normalize function